# Создание объектов "на лету"

Tags: ооп, php

**Всем доброго дня!**

Раньше, при создании объекта класса, я как-то не задумывался об удобном создании объекта и использования его полезного функционала "на лету"( т.е в строчку ). Наверное, львиная доля ОО-языков поддерживает эту фичу. Как же обстоят дела с тем же самым в PHP?

Обычно используется полезный функционал класса путем первоначального создания объекта и последующим вызовом его методов/использования переменных класса:

```
$OBJECT = new Object();
$OBJECT -> CallUsefulMethod();
```

Но во многих случаях точно известно, что объект будет использоваться единожды, следовательно, в присвоении его какой-л. переменной нет смысла. Впрочем, в этом и заключается прелесть создания "на лету". Есть ли способы делать в PHP что-то вроде такого(?):

```
(new Object()) -> CallUsefulMethod();
```

**Спасибо ;)**

Comment: Простите, но я таки не удержусь от встречного вопроса. А зачем это собственно? Если вы пишите класс, чтобы использовать его единственный метод и сразу о нем забыть, вам класс попросту не нужен, вам нужна функция. Не стоит городить ООП ради ООП.

Comment: Нет, класс инкапсулирует крупную логически объединенную структуру, элементы которой активно взаимодействуют друг с другом. Но также, порой, приходится получать из класса какие-то данные, которые, собственно, и хотелось бы получать на лету, без вспомогательных переменных.

Comment: Думаю вам подойдут статические методы, их можно использовать вообше без объявления класса http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Не нужно мне объяснять, что такое статика в ООП :)  Она не подойдет, так как данные генерируются в соответствии с входными параметрами, которые, в свою очередь, разные. Значит, как понимаю, создавать объекты "на лету" нельзя в PHP ? :(

Comment: >А зачем это собственно?

это может иметь смысл в случае, если использование объекта именно таким образом подразумевается не во всех случаях. Так или иначе, возможность небесполезная, и, честно говоря, я удивлюсь, если в php этого нет

Comment: Да, к сожалению, в PHP этого правда нет. "Зачем это собственно!" - ну, например, затем, чтобы логические блоки были объединены и не пришлось плодить множество функций вида `"Select_Name", "Select_Name_Formated", "Select_Name_URL"`. Все таки придется иметь дело с тем, что есть...без полета.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто создать инстанс класса и держать где нибудь ссылку на него и вызывать по мере необходимости? Создавать объекты таким образом в РНР это дорогая операция.

Comment: @zhenyab, тоже неплохой метод, даже, наверное, наилучший :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh)](/users/10774/0xffh) еще вы можете написать метод `create` и пользовать его вместо new:

```
public static function create($args) {
  $obj = new self;
  // some code
  return $obj;
}
```

Технически почти то же самое, но объяекты вполне себе создаются с учетом входных параметров.

```
$catsMeow = Cat::create($color, $height, $length)->SayMeow();
```

А если методы возвращают `$this` - можно и цепочки а ля `jQuery` создавать

```
$cat = Cat::create('white', 10, 30)->feed($meat)->colorize('black');
```

Небольшой листинг кода по комментарию

```
<?php

class Cat {
  private $color = 'red';
  private $height = 15;
  private $length = 45;
  private $meow = 'Meow';
  function create() {
    $obj = new self;

    return $obj;
  }
  function set($property, $value) {
    $this->{$property} = $value;
    return $this;
  }
  function execute($method, $args = array()) {
    $cb = array($this, $method);
    if (is_callable($cb))
      call_user_func_array($cb, $args);
    return $this;
  }

  function sayMeow() {
    echo $this->meow . '<br />';
  }
}

$cat = Cat::create()
  ->set('color', 'white')
  ->set('height', 10)
  ->execute('sayMeow')
  ->set('meow', 'Myaaaw')
  ->execute('sayMeow');
?>

out:
  Meow
  Myaaaw
```

Comment: @0xFFh переделал :)

Тогда еще порекомендую для комплекта метод `->set($property, $value)`, возвращающий `$this`, и `execute`, исполняющий метод и так же возвращающий `$this` (независимо от возвращаемого значения метода). Пхп-шный код становится необычным, но красивым)

Добавил листинг в ответ

Answer (score 6):

Увы, PHP не поддерживает анонимных объектов. 
Можно использовать паттерн "Singleton".

```
<?php
 class Cat {
    protected static $instance;  // object instance
    private function __construct() { ; }  //constructor block
    private function __clone() { ; }  //cloning block
    private function __wakeup()   { ; } //unserialize block
    public static function getInstance() {
        if ( !isset(self::$instance) ) {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $class();
            return self::$instance;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function SayMeow() { echo("Meow!"); }
 }
 Cat::getInstance()->SayMeow(); //using
?>
```

Comment: Кот-анонимус =)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Решение базируется все на той же статике инкапсулируемой "не менее статичным" паттерном. Так что, по сути, ничего нового.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне можно (испробовано на php7):

```
<?php
class A
{
    public function sayB()
    {
      echo 'I say B';
    }
}

(new A())->sayB();
```

Только стоит задуматься о целесообразности - ведь объект будет создан в памяти но на него не будет ссылки. После использования нужного метода, вы не сможете при необходимости удалить объект. Он будет удален из памяти только при заврешении работы всего вашего скрипта.

Comment: В догонку к сказанному: в вашем примере $OBJECT = new Object(); переменная $OBJECT  - это указатель на экземпляр класса (объект), а не переменная в которой он содержится. Чтобы память не "утекала" нужно все же создать объект классически через new, а затем $OBJECT = null  - удалить указатель. Будет "магически" вызван деструктор и удалит объект из памяти.

Comment: комментарий "в догонку" перенесите в тело ответа если он к нему относится. Нажмите кнопку "править" под ответом и внесите соответствующие изменения.

Comment: Такие inline-ы только в 7 версии и появились. Не понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под "утеканием" памяти, если все под контролем gc? И объект будет удален не после завершения скрипта, а после возврата из метода, иными словами - выхода за пределы своего namespace`а

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->property1 = 'string';
    $obj->property2 = 13;
```